# With the Python-Binance API, my limit order is only partially filled

Tags: python, python-3.x, binance, binance-api-client

I'm using Python 3.9 and the Python - Binance API, version python-binance==1.0.15.  In their test environment, I'm placing buy orders like so

```
order=self._get_auth_client(account).order_limit_buy(symbol=formatted_name, 
                                                     quantity=amount, 
                                                     price=fiat_price)
```

This returns the following JSON

```
{'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'orderId': 2603582, 'orderListId': -1, 'clientOrderId': 'Ru4Vv2jmxHIfGI21vIMtjD', 'transactTime': 1650828003836, 'price': '2915.16000000', 'origQty': '0.34303000', 'executedQty': '0.00000000', 'cummulativeQuoteQty': '0.00000000', 'status': 'NEW', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'type': 'LIMIT', 'side': 'BUY', 'fills': []}
```

Using the "orderId" field, I check the status of the order, and then get back the result

```
{'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'orderId': 2603582, 'orderListId': -1, 'clientOrderId': 'Ru4Vv2jmxHIfGI21vIMtjD', 'price': '2915.16000000', 'origQty': '0.34303000', 'executedQty': '0.08067000', 'cummulativeQuoteQty': '235.16595720', 'status': 'PARTIALLY_FILLED', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'type': 'LIMIT', 'side': 'BUY', 'stopPrice': '0.00000000', 'icebergQty': '0.00000000', 'time': 1650828003836, 'updateTime': 1650828050722, 'isWorking': True, 'origQuoteOrderQty': '0.00000000'}
```

the status indicates a partial fill.  I was wondering if there was a way to specify my buy order such that it either fills completely or not at all.  I don't see anything specified in their docs though but they are a little sparse.

Answer (score 2):

A partial fill order seems to be a common problem that has been discussed on [Reddit](https://www.google.com/search?q=binance%20PARTIALLY%20FILLED%20site:www.reddit.com&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS883US883&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZ2uSBlr73AhUEDkQIHfZ6COkQrQIoBHoECAQQBQ&biw=1465&bih=850&dpr=1).

The following is from the [API documentation](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/binance.html?highlight=order_limit_buy#binance.client.Client.order_limit_buy) related to an `order_limit_buy`, which you are executing.

---

`order_limit_buy(timeInForce='GTC', **params)[source]`

Send in a new limit buy order

Any order with an icebergQty MUST have timeInForce set to GTC.

**Parameters:**

- symbol (str) – required
- quantity (decimal) – required
- price (str) – required
- timeInForce (str) – default Good till cancelled
- newClientOrderId (str) – A unique id for the order. Automatically generated if not sent.
- stopPrice (decimal) – Used with stop orders
- icebergQty (decimal) – Used with iceberg orders
- newOrderRespType (str) – Set the response JSON. ACK, RESULT, or FULL;  default: RESULT.
- recvWindow (int) – the number of milliseconds the request is valid for

**Returns:**. API response

See order endpoint for full response options

**Raises:**

- BinanceRequestException
- BinanceAPIException
- BinanceOrderException
- BinanceOrderMinAmountException
- BinanceOrderMinPriceException
- BinanceOrderMinTotalException
- BinanceOrderUnknownSymbolException
- BinanceOrderInactiveSymbolException

---

Below is the source code for the [order_limit_buy function](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/binance/client.html?highlight=order_limit_buy#)

```
def order_limit_buy(self, timeInForce=BaseClient.TIME_IN_FORCE_GTC, **params):
        """Send in a new limit buy order

        Any order with an icebergQty MUST have timeInForce set to GTC.

        :param symbol: required
        :type symbol: str
        :param quantity: required
        :type quantity: decimal
        :param price: required
        :type price: str
        :param timeInForce: default Good till cancelled
        :type timeInForce: str
        :param newClientOrderId: A unique id for the order. Automatically generated if not sent.
        :type newClientOrderId: str
        :param stopPrice: Used with stop orders
        :type stopPrice: decimal
        :param icebergQty: Used with iceberg orders
        :type icebergQty: decimal
        :param newOrderRespType: Set the response JSON. ACK, RESULT, or FULL; default: RESULT.
        :type newOrderRespType: str
        :param recvWindow: the number of milliseconds the request is valid for
        :type recvWindow: int

        :returns: API response

        See order endpoint for full response options

        :raises: BinanceRequestException, BinanceAPIException, BinanceOrderException, BinanceOrderMinAmountException, BinanceOrderMinPriceException, BinanceOrderMinTotalException, BinanceOrderUnknownSymbolException, BinanceOrderInactiveSymbolException

        """
        params.update({
            'side': self.SIDE_BUY,
        })
        return self.order_limit(timeInForce=timeInForce, **params)
```

---

Neither the API parameters or the Python `order_limit_buy` function make it clear how to prevent the *partial fill order* issue.

Here is your buy order:

```
order=self._get_auth_client(account).order_limit_buy(symbol=formatted_name, 
                                                     quantity=amount, 
                                                     price=fiat_price)
```

Your order has the 3 required parameters as stated in the API documentation:

- symbol (str) – required
- quantity (decimal) – required
- price (str) – required

I found the article [What Is a Stop-Limit Order?](https://academy.binance.com/en/articles/what-is-a-stop-limit-order) on the Binance Academy website. The article had this statement:

> If you're worried about your orders only partially filling, consider
> using fill or kill.

Based on this statement I started looking through the API documentation and the source code for how to set either a `FILL` or `KILL` order.

I noted that the Python `order_limit_buy` function has this parameter:

```
:param timeInForce: default Good till cancelled
:type timeInForce: str
```

The default value is `Good till cancelled` or `GTC`.

Looking at the API source code I found that the `timeInForce` parameter has 3 possible values:

```
TIME_IN_FORCE_GTC = 'GTC'  # Good till cancelled
TIME_IN_FORCE_IOC = 'IOC'  # Immediate or cancel
TIME_IN_FORCE_FOK = 'FOK'  # Fill or kill
```

Note the value `TIME_IN_FORCE_FOK` or `FOK`.

The following is from the [Binance API documentation on GitHub](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#public-api-definitions):

---

**Time in force (timeInForce):**

This sets how long an order will be active before expiration.

| Status | Description |
| --- | --- |
| GTC | Good Till Canceled An order will be on the book unless the order is canceled. |
| IOC | Immediate Or Cancel An order will try to fill the order as much as it can before the order expires. |
| FOK | Fill or Kill An order will expire if the full order cannot be filled upon execution |

---

Your buy request should look like this when using the `timeInForce` parameter with the value `FOK`:

```
order=self._get_auth_client(account).order_limit_buy(symbol=formatted_name, 
                                                     quantity=amount, 
                                                     price=fiat_price,
                                                     timeInForce='FOK')
```

I created a Binance TestNet Account and developed the code below as a test. I set my target price at 2687.00 to buy ETHUSDT. I used a loop to place my limited buy and to check to see if it was filled.

```
from binance.client import Client

api_key = 'my key'
api_secret = 'my secret'
client = Client(api_key, api_secret, testnet=True)

order_status = True
while True:
    limit_order = client.order_limit_buy(symbol="ETHUSDT", quantity=0.01, price='2687.00', timeInForce='FOK')
    ticker = client.get_ticker(symbol="ETHUSDT")
    print(f"Current Price: {ticker.get('askPrice')}")
    print(limit_order)
    _status = limit_order.get('status')
    if _status == 'FILLED':
        order_status = False
        print(order_status)
        break
    elif _status == 'EXPIRED':
        order_status = True
```

The output from the code above is below:

NOTE: this is a snippet of the output, because the loop will run until the buy order triggers.

```
Current Price: 2687.33000000
{'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'orderId': 962373, 'orderListId': -1, 'clientOrderId': 'nW7bI2tkTwQEvrb8sSqgM6', 'transactTime': 1651927994444, 'price': '2687.00000000', 'origQty': '0.01000000', 'executedQty': '0.00000000', 'cummulativeQuoteQty': '0.00000000', 'status': 'EXPIRED', 'timeInForce': 'FOK', 'type': 'LIMIT', 'side': 'BUY', 'fills': []}

Current Price: 2687.33000000
{'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'orderId': 962378, 'orderListId': -1, 'clientOrderId': '7MPoHZDykxsK3Oqo7uOB78', 'transactTime': 1651927995310, 'price': '2687.00000000', 'origQty': '0.01000000', 'executedQty': '0.00000000', 'cummulativeQuoteQty': '0.00000000', 'status': 'EXPIRED', 'timeInForce': 'FOK', 'type': 'LIMIT', 'side': 'BUY', 'fills': []}

Current Price: 2687.33000000
{'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'orderId': 962387, 'orderListId': -1, 'clientOrderId': '3mRS9GK6pfGpqaqU9SK1vK', 'transactTime': 1651927996177, 'price': '2687.00000000', 'origQty': '0.01000000', 'executedQty': '0.00000000', 'cummulativeQuoteQty': '0.00000000', 'status': 'EXPIRED', 'timeInForce': 'FOK', 'type': 'LIMIT', 'side': 'BUY', 'fills': []}

Current Price: 2687.33000000
{'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'orderId': 962395, 'orderListId': -1, 'clientOrderId': '8yTAtrsjNH2PELtg93SdH3', 'transactTime': 1651927997041, 'price': '2687.00000000', 'origQty': '0.01000000', 'executedQty': '0.00000000', 'cummulativeQuoteQty': '0.00000000', 'status': 'EXPIRED', 'timeInForce': 'FOK', 'type': 'LIMIT', 'side': 'BUY', 'fills': []}

Current Price: 2687.06000000
{'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'orderId': 962403, 'orderListId': -1, 'clientOrderId': '5q8GPEg5bYgzoW7PUnR2VN', 'transactTime': 1651927997903, 'price': '2687.00000000', 'origQty': '0.01000000', 'executedQty': '0.00000000', 'cummulativeQuoteQty': '0.00000000', 'status': 'EXPIRED', 'timeInForce': 'FOK', 'type': 'LIMIT', 'side': 'BUY', 'fills': []}

Current Price: 2686.87000000
{'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'orderId': 962420, 'orderListId': -1, 'clientOrderId': 'ENxCN1JAW4OcxLiAkSmdIH', 'transactTime': 1651927999639, 'price': '2687.00000000', 'origQty': '0.01000000', 'executedQty': '0.01000000', 'cummulativeQuoteQty': '26.86870000', 'status': 'FILLED', 'timeInForce': 'FOK', 'type': 'LIMIT', 'side': 'BUY', 'fills': [{'price': '2686.87000000', 'qty': '0.01000000', 'commission': '0.00000000', 'commissionAsset': 'ETH', 'tradeId': 225595}]}
False # loop closed
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible. This is due to the nature of an exchange order-matching system. When you send an order to **buy** 0.34303ETH @2915.16, the exchange looks for people who wants to **sell** ETH @2915.16, aka. the counter-party. However the amount they want to sell can rarely be exactly 0.34303ETH. It can be greater or lesser than this quantity. That's why you can get partially filled when the market moves around the price level specified vastly.

Comment: Thanks but that's not true on normal exchanges.  For example, with Fidelity, I can specify that I want the order to fill entirely or not at all.  I just don't know the Binance API well enough to know hot to specify such an option (or if their exchange supports it)

Comment: I only have experience in crypto trading but not in traditional market. Apologies. My guess is crypto has a spirit of brining everything as granular as possible, so that might be a subtle difference between the two markets.